# How to integrate Pinterest in my Android application?

Tags: android, social-networking, pinterest

I need to integrate [pinterest](http://pinterest.com/) in my application. I need to share images in Pinterest through my app. I have gone through this document [Pinterest Developer](http://developers.pinterest.com/android/), there is only one API to Pin image. Please provide me official documents links to share image.